# proguard Missing type parameter

Tags: android, proguard

i try obfuscate my code of android app with `ProGuard`. But after this my app give exception at running:

```
11-15 01:46:26.818: W/System.err(21810): java.lang.RuntimeException: Missing type parameter.
11-15 01:46:26.828: W/System.err(21810):    at da.<init>(Unknown Source)
11-15 01:46:26.828: W/System.err(21810):    at gc.<init>(Unknown Source)
11-15 01:46:26.828: W/System.err(21810):    at fx.f(Unknown Source)
11-15 01:46:26.828: W/System.err(21810):    at com.yourshows.activity.UnwatchedActivity.onResume(Unknown Source)
```

I checked a `mapping` file and found this:

```
com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken -> da:
```

I think it's lines in my app like:

```
        Type mapType = new TypeToken<Map<Integer, WatchedEpisodes>>(){}.getType(); // define generic type
        jsData = gson.fromJson(r, mapType);
```

I can not understand what conclusions should I do? Do not use variable name less then three characters or what?

UPD: [answer](http://groups.google.com/group/google-gson/browse_thread/thread/e97b877cea1920aa)

Comment: You can post an answer of your own, because questions like these may be automatically deleted.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

answer is: use this proguard.cfg

```
##---------------Begin: proguard configuration common for all Android apps ----------
-optimizationpasses 5
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers
-dontpreverify
-verbose
-dump class_files.txt 
-printseeds seeds.txt 
-printusage unused.txt 
-printmapping mapping.txt 
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*


-allowaccessmodification
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
-repackageclasses ''


-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgentHelper
-keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService
-dontnote com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService


# Explicitly preserve all serialization members. The Serializable interface
# is only a marker interface, so it wouldn't save them.
-keepclassmembers class * implements java.io.Serializable {
    static final long serialVersionUID;
    private static final java.io.ObjectStreamField[] serialPersistentFields;
    private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream);
    private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream);
    java.lang.Object writeReplace();
    java.lang.Object readResolve();
}


# Preserve all native method names and the names of their classes.
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}


-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}


-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}


# Preserve static fields of inner classes of R classes that might be accessed
# through introspection.
-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
  public static <fields>;
}


# Preserve the special static methods that are required in all enumeration classes.
-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}


-keep public class * {
    public protected *;
}


-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}
##---------------End: proguard configuration common for all Android apps ----------


##---------------Begin: proguard configuration for Gson  ----------
# Gson uses generic type information stored in a class file when working with fields. Proguard
# removes such information by default, so configure it to keep all of it.
-keepattributes Signature


# Gson specific classes
-keep class sun.misc.Unsafe { *; }
#-keep class com.google.gson.stream.** { *; }


# Application classes that will be serialized/deserialized over Gson
-keep class com.google.gson.examples.android.model.** { *; }


##---------------End: proguard configuration for Gson  ----------
```

Big thanks to owner this project --> [google-gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)

---

**UPD**: 
`google/gson` has their example of proguard configuration for android applications.

[see on github](https://github.com/google/gson/tree/master/examples/android-proguard-example)

They propose to use this template of configuration

```
##---------------Begin: proguard configuration for Gson  ----------
# Gson uses generic type information stored in a class file when working with fields. Proguard
# removes such information by default, so configure it to keep all of it.
-keepattributes Signature

# For using GSON @Expose annotation
-keepattributes *Annotation*

# Gson specific classes
-keep class sun.misc.Unsafe { *; }
#-keep class com.google.gson.stream.** { *; }

# Application classes that will be serialized/deserialized over Gson
-keep class com.google.gson.examples.android.model.** { *; }

##---------------End: proguard configuration for Gson  ----------
```

Comment: lint says: use -keepclasseswithmembers instead of -keepclasseswithmembernames

Comment: I really don't know why but I have copied all this and pasted to proguard-project.txt but the same error still occurred!

Comment: I don't know what proguard-project.txt is. But i use this settings in `proguard.cfg`. Maybe you used not correct file for settings up your obfuscator? Try to ask a new question with more detail.

Comment: @Mrusful I obfuscate my code with Eclipse that's why the config is saved in proguard-project.txt in default. And here is my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18168388/android-parsing-gson-not-working-after-obfuscating

Answer (score 44):

Since I didn't notice the link in the question at first, here are the specific lines mentioned in the thread needed to get GSON to work with Proguard:

```
# Gson uses generic type information stored in a class file when working with fields. Proguard
# removes such information by default, so configure it to keep all of it.
-keepattributes Signature

# Gson specific classes
-keep class sun.misc.Unsafe { *; }
#-keep class com.google.gson.stream.** { *; }

# Application classes that will be serialized/deserialized over Gson
-keep class com.google.gson.examples.android.model.** { *; }
```

Answer (score 3):

This issue can be solved by using a different way to create the `TypeToken` instance (for the parameterized type `Map<Integer, WatchedEpisodes>`):

```
Type collectionType = 
  TypeToken.get(
    $Gson$Types.newParameterizedTypeWithOwner(null,
      Map.class, Integer.class, WatchedEpisodes.class)).getType();
```

The next version of gson (I assume 2.8), will allow you to type this more easily:

```
Type collectionType =
  TypeToken.getParameterized(Map.class,
                             Integer.class,
                             WatchedEpisodes.class).getType();
```

Comment: I was having obfuscation problems recently, when I upgraded my Gradle Plugin from `7.x` to `8.x`. Changing from `new TypeToken...` to `TypeToken.getParameterized...` solved these issues!

Answer (score 0):

The current answer didn't solve my problem. Here is my solution:

Add these lines to your `proguard-rules.pro` file:

```
##---------------Begin: proguard configuration for Gson  ----------
# Gson uses generic type information stored in a class file when working with fields. Proguard
# removes such information by default, so configure it to keep all of it.
-keepattributes Signature

# For using GSON @Expose annotation
-keepattributes *Annotation*

# Gson specific classes
-dontwarn sun.misc.**
#-keep class com.google.gson.stream.** { *; }

# Application classes that will be serialized/deserialized over Gson
-keep class PATH_TO_YOUR_MODELS_PACKAGE.models.** { *; }

# Prevent proguard from stripping interface information from TypeAdapter, TypeAdapterFactory,
# JsonSerializer, JsonDeserializer instances (so they can be used in @JsonAdapter)
-keep class * extends com.google.gson.TypeAdapter
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.TypeAdapterFactory
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.JsonSerializer
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.JsonDeserializer

# Prevent R8 from leaving Data object members always null
-keepclassmembers,allowobfuscation class * {
  @com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName <fields>;
}

# Retain generic signatures of TypeToken and its subclasses with R8 version 3.0 and higher.
-keep,allowobfuscation,allowshrinking class com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken
-keep,allowobfuscation,allowshrinking class * extends com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken

##---------------End: proguard configuration for Gson  ----------
```

**Important Note:**

You should put all your models that work with gson in a package and exclude it from minify using this proguard rule:

```
 -keep class PATH_TO_YOUR_MODELS_PACKAGE.** { *; }
```

change it based on your package name. **for example** if your models are in `com.example.models` you should have this line:

```
 -keep class com.example.models.** { *; }
```