# FlexJson deserializer not working after obfuscating code

Tags: android, android-build, flexjson

FlexJson is working great with deep serialize where i have objects inside objects..But i see that after obfuscating my build with proguard my deserialized class returns just the class object in String..Or anything i have to change in the local.properties or project.properties

And yes using Console and ANT i am upadting my code where (android update ....--library) links to path of the folder of my library code.Here flexjson is just a jar on my /libs folder of project.If the issue is with not referencing library kindly help with how to do it??

Or else any other issue help!!!

in my proguard.cfg i have written this

```
-keep class flexjson.** { *; }
```

its not throwing ClassNotFoundException but serialize,deepserialize,deserialize not working

AND I HAVE ALREADY OBFUSCATED MY CODE WITH EVERYTHING PROPERLY RUNNING EXCEPT THIS

Comment: its not working yet..help

Comment: No replies yet!!! any help will be welcomed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okk i got the answer here..Even GSON library was throwing the same error while deserializing.So the issue is same with all generic typw object serialization...I found the  soultion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8129040/proguard-missing-type-parameter)