# Proguard: how obfuscate just two method?

Tags: android, proguard, obfuscation

I try use just it in proguard-rule.txt

```
-keep class !com.some.package.MyActivity { 
            private void onePrivateMethod(); 
            private void twoPrivateMethod(); 
}
```

But happens error.

```
Warning:'com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest$Builder setLocation(android.location.Location)' in program class com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest$Builder
Warning:there were 1 unresolved references to program class members.
         Your input classes appear to be inconsistent.
         You may need to recompile the code.       
         (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedprogramclassmember)    
:proguardRelease FAILED
Error:Execution failed for task ':proguardRelease'.
> java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
```

I try rebuild project.

**UPD**  logcat after adding `-dontwarn com.google.**`

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Missing type parameter.
01-21 13:24:19.191  22884-23039/ru.my.package W/System.err﹕ at com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken.getSuperclassTypeParameter(Unknown Source)
01-21 13:24:19.191  22884-23039/ru.my.package W/System.err﹕ at com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken.<init>(Unknown Source)
01-21 13:24:19.191  22884-23039/ru.my.package W/System.err﹕ at ru.my.package.util.JsonMaster$1.<init>(Unknown Source)
01-21 13:24:19.191  22884-23039/ru.my.package W/System.err﹕ at ru.my.package.util.JsonMaster.parseListOfCity(Unknown Source)
01-21 13:24:19.191  22884-23039/ru.my.package W/System.err﹕ at ru.my.package.api.server.AsyncCitiesListDownloader.doInBackground(Unknown Source)
01-21 13:24:19.191  22884-23039/ru.my.package W/System.err﹕ at ru.my.package.api.server.AsyncCitiesListDownloader.doInBackground(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: don´t know how, but the first error with the admob You can prevent by enter into proguard : -dontwarn com.google.gms.**

Comment: @Opiatefuchs okey, it work. but now was obfuscated all other classes and application crashed

Comment: also I try add -keep class ru.my.package.**

Comment: don´t know if this is the issue, but be sure that You wrote -dontwarn com.google.gms.** not -dontwarn com.google.** .

Comment: @Opiatefuchs i use -dontwarn com.google.andoird.gms.**

Comment: ok, then it is good. keep this in Your config, that´s ok, Your new error has nothing to do with that. It seems a gson problem. look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8129040/proguard-missing-type-parameter

Comment: but why? I set to obfuscation just one class. If I use them config, my class did't obfuscate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In summary, thank @Opiatefuchs for help.
I moved the necessary methods in a external class and now I use config.
Allows obfuscate class `com.my.pakage.SomeClass` and app work perfectly.
Based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/8181232/1654690

```
-optimizationpasses 5
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers
-dontpreverify
-verbose
-dump class_files.txt
-printseeds seeds.txt
-printusage unused.txt
-printmapping mapping.txt
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*

-allowaccessmodification
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
-repackageclasses ''
-dontwarn com.google.andoird.gms.**
-dontwarn ru.adcamp.ads.**

## Class to obfuscate
-keep class !com.my.pakage.SomeClass{ *; }

-keep class ru.**{*;}

##---------------Begin: proguard configuration for Gson  ----------
# Gson uses generic type information stored in a class file when working with fields. Proguard
# removes such information by default, so configure it to keep all of it.
-keepattributes Signature

# Gson specific classes
-keep class sun.misc.Unsafe { *; }
#-keep class com.google.gson.stream.** { *; }

##---------------End: proguard configuration for Gson  ----------

##=============== ADDITIONAL ==============

-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}

# Explicitly preserve all serialization members. The Serializable interface
# is only a marker interface, so it wouldn't save them.
-keepclassmembers class * implements java.io.Serializable {
    static final long serialVersionUID;
    private static final java.io.ObjectStreamField[] serialPersistentFields;
    private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream);
    private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream);
    java.lang.Object writeReplace();
    java.lang.Object readResolve();
}

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgentHelper
-keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService
-dontnote com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService

# Preserve all native method names and the names of their classes.
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

# Preserve static fields of inner classes of R classes that might be accessed
# through introspection.
-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
  public static <fields>;
}
```