# App running in debug, not in release

Tags: android, debugging, release

my app runs fine in debug mode.

Now I changed to release mode and get logcat below.

There is no information about the error. Again, its running without any issue in debug mode.

```
09-17 20:06:07.915  30204-30204/? D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
09-17 20:06:07.915  30204-30204/? W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41fa9668)
09-17 20:06:07.925  30204-30204/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: eu.straff, PID: 30204
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Missing type parameter.
            at a.b.a.c.a.a(Unknown Source)
            at a.b.a.c.a.<init>(Unknown Source)
            at eu.straff.ag.<init>(Unknown Source)
            at eu.straff.af.a(Unknown Source)
            at eu.straff.af.a(Unknown Source)
            at a.a.a.a.o.c(Unknown Source)
            at a.a.a.a.o.b(Unknown Source)
            at a.a.a.i.run(Unknown Source)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:212)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5137)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:902)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:718)
            at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:132)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-17 20:06:07.925    1263-1592/? D/ActivityManager﹕ New dropbox entry: eu.straff, data_app_crash, bb25e471-c278-4c6f-8a6c-89bc63f8451f
09-17 20:06:07.925    1263-1592/? W/ActivityManager﹕ Force finishing activity eu.straff/.SelectKostActivity
09-17 20:06:07.945    1263-1817/? D/Ulp_jni﹕ Location CB invoked
09-17 20:06:08.025  28721-30302/? I/CrashMonitor﹕ CrashMonitorServiceBroadcastReceiver: Forwarding intent: android.intent.action.DROPBOX_ENTRY_ADDED tag: data_app_crash
09-17 20:06:08.025  28721-28721/? I/CrashMonitor﹕ CrashMonitorService: Service started...
09-17 20:06:08.035  17374-17385/? I/tfsw﹕ Foreground was changed: eu.straff
```

Comment: Found the solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8129040/proguard-missing-type-parameter

Comment: set your minifyEnabled false and try again.