# Why do I get a Theming error just after using Proguard?

Tags: android, themes, proguard

I never used proguard before, and now force to use it due to the nasty Samsung bug: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=78377

So, basically, I followed all the explanations, and added this in my gradle file:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

    }
}
```

and my file contains the line I need to workaround the above bug:

```
-keep class !android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.**,** {*;}
```

[image]

Note: I have followed many and many proguard template files, and tried a lot of code there, so don't know what to do.

The app compiles just fine in debug, on my phone, but once I try to compile the apk and upload it, I got this error:

```
IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
```

Please, do not point me to the style.xml, the Theme IS Appcompat, and it works fine on debug.

Thank a lot for any help, or hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally used this file: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8181232/327402

Working fine now.

```
##---------------Begin: proguard configuration common for all Android apps ----------
-optimizationpasses 5
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers
-dontpreverify
-verbose
-dump class_files.txt 
-printseeds seeds.txt 
-printusage unused.txt 
-printmapping mapping.txt 
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*


-allowaccessmodification
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
-repackageclasses ''


-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgentHelper
-keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService
-dontnote com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService


# Explicitly preserve all serialization members. The Serializable interface
# is only a marker interface, so it wouldn't save them.
-keepclassmembers class * implements java.io.Serializable {
    static final long serialVersionUID;
    private static final java.io.ObjectStreamField[] serialPersistentFields;
    private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream);
    private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream);
    java.lang.Object writeReplace();
    java.lang.Object readResolve();
}


# Preserve all native method names and the names of their classes.
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}


-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}


-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}


# Preserve static fields of inner classes of R classes that might be accessed
# through introspection.
-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
  public static <fields>;
}


# Preserve the special static methods that are required in all enumeration classes.
-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}


-keep public class * {
    public protected *;
}


-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}
##---------------End: proguard configuration common for all Android apps ----------


##---------------Begin: proguard configuration for Gson  ----------
# Gson uses generic type information stored in a class file when working with fields. Proguard
# removes such information by default, so configure it to keep all of it.
-keepattributes Signature


# Gson specific classes
-keep class sun.misc.Unsafe { *; }
#-keep class com.google.gson.stream.** { *; }


# Application classes that will be serialized/deserialized over Gson
-keep class com.google.gson.examples.android.model.** { *; }


##---------------End: proguard configuration for Gson  ----------
```