# java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError when button is clicked

Tags: java, android

I am making an app that tracks the user based on GPS.
When I press the button to move to another intent I get this error.
I didn't get this error when testing on Samsung Galaxy S5 with Android v6.
Error has appeared on HTC that has Android v4.4.4

Here's the error:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
                                                                                  at com.example.matej.locato.TrackingActivity.l(Unknown Source)
                                                                                  at com.example.matej.locato.TrackingActivity.b(Unknown Source)
                                                                                  at com.example.matej.locato.TrackingActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source)
                                                                                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5312)
                                                                                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1111)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2395)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2495)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:153)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1349)
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5633)
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:896)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:712)
                                                                                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                               Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Missing type parameter.
                                                                                  at com.google.a.c.a.a(Unknown Source)
                                                                                  at com.google.a.c.a.<init>(Unknown Source)
                                                                                  at com.google.a.k.<init>(Unknown Source)
                                                                                  at com.google.a.j.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
                                                                                  at com.example.matej.locato.TrackingActivity.l(Unknown Source) 
                                                                                  at com.example.matej.locato.TrackingActivity.b(Unknown Source) 
                                                                                  at com.example.matej.locato.TrackingActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source) 
                                                                                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5312) 
                                                                                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1111) 
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2395) 
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2495) 
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:153) 
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1349) 
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157) 
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5633) 
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:896) 
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:712) 
                                                                                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This is the button code :

```
public void button_click_clicked(View view) {

    // check if user has location
    if (user.updated) {
        // create new intent with TrackingActivity
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, TrackingActivity.class);

        // start activity
        startActivity(intent);

        //start tracking and create target
        //TrackingActivity.startTracking(user.updated);
    } else {
        // user has not received location yet
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please wait for GPS signal", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

And code for the Activity that throws the error:

```
package com.example.matej.locato;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.InputType;
import android.text.Layout;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.RotateAnimation;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.gson.Gson;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * @author Matej Ocovsky -- 9/7/2016
 */

public class TrackingActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SensorEventListener, OnMapReadyCallback {
public static boolean trackStart = false;

private static ImageView image;

private float currentDegree = 0f;

private SensorManager mSensorManager;

public static ArrayList<Target> targetList = new ArrayList<>();

public static GoogleMap mMap;

private static Target targetDislplayed;

public static SharedPreferences  mPrefs;




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tracking);



    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map_frag);
    //MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager() .findFragmentById(R.id.map_frag);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);


    // make textView that will be displaying current user location
    MainActivity.textView = new TextView(this);
    MainActivity.textView.setTextSize(30);
    MainActivity.textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFF4FE53"));

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    rlp.setMargins(150, 150, 0, 0);
    MainActivity.textView.setLayoutParams(rlp);



    // check whether user coordinates have been modified
    if(MainActivity.user.uLatitude == 0 && MainActivity.user.uLongitude == 0) {
        // by default it is gonna show this message
        MainActivity.textView.setText("Please wait for coordinates");
    }



    // find layout that we can display the text on
    RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.contentTrackingActivity);

    // add textView to the corresponding layout
    layout.addView(MainActivity.textView);


    image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.arrow_iv);

    mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    mSensorManager.registerListener(this,mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION),SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);

    mPrefs  = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);

    startTracking(MainActivity.user.updated);


}


public  void startTracking(boolean userUpdated) {

    if (userUpdated) {
        Target tryTarget = retrieveTarget();
        //Target tryTarget = null;
        TextView textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_notes);

        if (tryTarget == null) {

            // initialize target that is going to be tracked

            Target target = new Target(MainActivity.user.uLongitude, MainActivity.user.uLatitude);
            target.tLocation = MainActivity.currentLocation;
            saveTarget(target);

            resetParking(target);

        }
        else{
            saveTarget(tryTarget);

            resetParking(tryTarget);

            if(tryTarget.note == null || tryTarget.note == ""){
                textview.setText("Click to add notes");
            }
            else
            {
                textview.setText(tryTarget.note);
            }

        }
    }
        else {
            trackStart = false;
        }


}

public static Target getTarget(String targetName){
    if(targetList.isEmpty())
    {
        return null;
    }
    else{
        for(Target target : targetList){
            if(target.name.equals(targetName)) {
                return target;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}

public void openMap(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, TrackMap.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}


@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    //degree between phone y axis and magnetic north
    Float azimuth = (float) Math.round(event.values[0]);

    //we need target location object
    Target target = getTarget("Car");

    // get bearing between phone and target
    Float bearing = MainActivity.currentLocation.bearingTo(target.tLocation);

    //calculate the direction to which the arrow will be poinitng
    Float direction = azimuth - bearing;

    //arrow that will be rotating
    RotateAnimation ra = new RotateAnimation(currentDegree, -direction, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);

    //one second
    ra.setDuration(1000);
    ra.setFillAfter(true);
    image.startAnimation(ra);
    currentDegree = -direction;
}

@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
    //not needed
}


@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    targetDislplayed = TrackingActivity.getTarget("Car");

    // Add a marker at user location and move the camera
    LatLng userLocation = new LatLng(targetDislplayed.tLatitude, targetDislplayed.tLongitude);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(targetDislplayed.tLatitude, targetDislplayed.tLongitude))
            .title("Target"));

    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(userLocation));

    // doesnt need permission check because the code in previous itents would allow user to open this map without the permission, might add it just for fun :D
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);



}


public static void saveTarget(Target tempTarget){

    //mPrefs  = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);

    SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = mPrefs.edit();


    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(tempTarget);
    prefsEditor.putString("SavedTarget", json);
    prefsEditor.apply();
    //mPrefs.edit().putString("SavedTarget",json).apply();

}

public static Target retrieveTarget(){
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = mPrefs.getString("SavedTarget","");

    Target returnedTarget = null;

    returnedTarget = gson.fromJson(json, Target.class);

    return returnedTarget;
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    //startTracking(MainActivity.user.updated);
}

public void resetParking(Target target){
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_notes);
    textView.setText("Click to add notes");

    if (targetList.isEmpty()) {
        targetList.add(target);
        MainActivity.targetTracked = target;

        trackStart = true;
    } else {
        Target tempTarget = getTarget("Car");
        targetList.remove(tempTarget);

        targetList.add(target);
        MainActivity.targetTracked = target;
        trackStart = true;
    }
}

public void resetParkingButtonClicked(View view){



    //Toast.makeText(TrackingActivity.this, "Canceled reset action", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to reset the parking location?");
    builder.setTitle("Reset parking location");
    builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            //clicked ok button
            Target target = new Target(MainActivity.user.uLongitude, MainActivity.user.uLatitude);
            target.tLocation = MainActivity.currentLocation;
            saveTarget(target);
            resetParking(target);
            mMap.clear();
            TrackingActivity.mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(target.tLatitude, target.tLongitude))
                    .title("Target"));
        }
    });

    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Toast.makeText(TrackingActivity.this, "Canceled reset action", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.show();


}
public void textViewAddNote(View view){
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Add note");
    final EditText input = new EditText(this);
    input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
    builder.setView(input);
    builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Target target = getTarget("Car");
            target.note = input.getText().toString();
            TextView textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_notes);
            textview.setText(target.note);
            saveTarget(target);
        }
    });

    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Toast.makeText(TrackingActivity.this, "Canceled note action", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.show();
}
```

}

My dependencies:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.matej.locato"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    // Enabling multidex support.
    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    debug {
        minifyEnabled true
    }
}
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
```

tried to update the proguard-rules.pro but it has no effect, I am still getting the error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [proguard Missing type parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8129040/proguard-missing-type-parameter)

Comment: I have built apk and instaled that one on my S5, it crashes too when I click on the button, so the code only works when loaded from android studio onto the phone, it doesnt work on the HTC in any case. So it must be something with code removal. I will look into the proguard file.

Comment: I have tried to add it to proguard rules pro but I still get the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have enabled `minifyEnabled true` in gradle-config, proguard can be the issue.

Try adding these lines in your `proguard-rules.pro`

```
-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
-keepattributes  Signature,SourceFile,LineNumberTable
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
```

Comment: I will try it out. The MainActivity is loaded completely fine and its only when the button is clicked that the next Activity crashes.

Comment: Could it be because i am using multidex?

Comment: Deleting the entrie content of proguard-rules.pro and then pasting this into the file has fixed the problem. Thank you so much.

Comment: @MatejOčovský AFAIK, when you set minifyEnabled to true, proguard does not compile unused classes and functions, but are necessary. By adding above lines we tell proguard to keep them even if it think they are not necessary.  I recommend that, if you are implementing a new feature/experimenting with your app, please set minifyEnabled to false. After ensuring proper functioning of app, then enable minifyEnabled function. Also read this.
https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass context properly
Change

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, TrackingActivity.class);
```

To

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Activity.this, TrackingActivity.class);
```