# java.lang.RuntimeException: Missing type parameter

Tags: java, android, gson

My project encountered this error:

[image]

I tried to fix it using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8129040/proguard-missing-type-parameter?) link

but I can not because I do not really understand the answer. Please tell me how to fix it. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class `TypeToken` requires a type parameter.

Looking at your code, it looks like you should replace

```
Type listType = new TypeToken() {
}.getType();
```

with

```
Type listType = new TypeToken<List<Face>>() {
}.getType();
```

Comment: Glad I could help. :)

Answer (score 75):

I faced the same issue with Gson library and searched for the solution a lot but none of them work for me then I read the R8 full mode true changes and added this three-line in proguard and it worked fine for me.

if someone face the same issue, you can try this:

```
-keep class com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken
-keep class * extends com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken
-keep public class * implements java.lang.reflect.Type
```

Comment: This occurs in signed APK, if you have debug APK you probably wont get this error. I was wondering. why this happens. then your answer gave what I needed to know.

Comment: Thank you!!! This saved me from the weird bug that only appears in the release build.

Comment: It's no weird, It happens only on release build because minifyEnabled (Inside gradle file) which make the code obfuscated probably set to true on only on release build,

Comment: Which is why I now have minifyEnabled set to true on debug as well, I want to know about these elusive errors way before I try to release, not on the night we are trying to release.

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/examples/android-proguard-example/proguard.cfg) you have an example of a proguard for Android to be compatible with Gson. I had the same problem and solved it with this configuration.

Comment: working.. idk why these bugs occur

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me, and the error didn't even come from Gson.

Comment: Thank you for this lifesaver. It would be great if someone could explain what "-keep class * extends" and "-keep public class * implements" mean. R8 has been a disaster for us in the past few years.

Comment: Full explanation: [AGP 8.0.0 changed the default value for R8 full mode to `true`](https://developer.android.com/build/releases/past-releases/agp-8-0-0-release-notes#default-changes), which means "R8 performs more aggressive optimizations". Known issues [are listed here](https://r8.googlesource.com/r8/+/refs/heads/master/compatibility-faq.md#troubleshooting), incl. solutions for GSON (and retrofit). It mentions similar proguard additions:
`-keepattributes Signature
-keep class com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken { *; }
-keep class * extends com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken`

Comment: This worked for me. I had to add it to each module's pro-guard rules