# compileKotlin Failed

Tags: kotlin, gradle, intellij-idea, compiler-errors

I have an error problem with compileKotlin in IntelliJ IDEA. Tried changing the previous jvm or java version but still having the error as shown. can anyone help me solve this problem?

[image: this is a picture of the problem]

Comment: Try changing Kotlin/Java versions as per https://stackoverflow.com/a/69084853/12844632

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does `App.kt` have this at the top?

```
package kotlin.kotlin.unit.test
```

You'll get that `Only the Kotlin standard library is allowed to use the 'kotlin' package` error if you do that - your package names can't start with `kotlin.`. Just use `com.example.coolapps` or something if you don't have your own domain.

If you rename it, Android Studio will complain that the package name doesn't match the file's location (the package needs to match the folder structure - see in the path it's currently `kotlin/kotlin/unit/test`) but if you Alt+Enter or click the light bulb icon, it'll offer to move it to `com/example/coolapps` for you

Comment: app/src/main/kotlin/kotlin/unit/test/App.kt

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA, from the first time I made an application like this. So what should I do?

Comment: @DendiPrayogoHidayat Android Studio is based on IDEA so it should still work. Every Android app needs a package name - there's some info here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6273892 Your package name isn't allowed to start with ``kotlin`` as the first part, so you need to change it. Here's a way you can change it for the whole app: https://abhiandroid.com/androidstudio/how-to-change-package-name-android-studio.html

Comment: it's solved. thank you brother. appreciated