# 'kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin' task (current target is 17) jvm target compatibility should be set to the same Java version

Tags: kotlin

I faced the following error when upgrading a Jetpack Compose project from AGP 7.4.0 to 8.1.0-beta05:

```
    Execution failed for task ':app:kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin'. > 'compileDebugJavaWithJavac' task (current target is 1.8) and 'kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin' task (current target is 17) jvm target compatibility should be set to the same Java version.   Consider using JVM toolchain: https://kotl.in/gradle/jvm/toolchain
```

I tried to specify a JVM toolchain using

```
java {
//...
}
```

but it kept complaining with the same error. The similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69079963/how-to-set-compilejava-task-11-and-compilekotlin-task-1-8-jvm-target-com) suggests using a java block and setting sourceCompatibility and targetCompatibility to Java 11. This also didn't work.

Answer (score 12):

As hinted in the error, the current JVM target seems to be set to 17 in AGP 8.0 onwards. However, we have historically set the targetCompability and sourceCompatibility to Java 8 in our Compose projects (even in official Compose documentation). The solution involves two changes in app/build.gradle:
1- Change Java version in compileOptions from 1_8 to 17:

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
}
```

2- Change jvmTarget in kotlinOptions:

```
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = '17'
}
```

Sync the project and the project should build successfully now.

Comment: Had a similar error and although these attributes were correct, android studio and my system (class paths) were pointing to different versions of Java. Aligning them solved this issue for me.

Answer (score 4):

Android Studio IDE is using 17 (You can find it in File Menu->Project Structure->SDK Location->JDK location)

And You are using 1.8 in your gradle files. use same version for both.

```
   compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_18
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_18
}
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = "18"
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This command is used to configure the KaptGenerateStubs tasks in a Gradle project to set the jvmTarget to Java 8.

gradle

```
tasks.withType(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KaptGenerateStubs).configureEach{
kotlinOptions{
jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
}
```

or kotlin DSL

```
tasks.withType<org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KaptGenerateStubs> {
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}
```