# Caused by java.lang.RuntimeException: Missing type parameter

Tags: android, kotlin, gson, proguard, typetoken

I'm retrieving a `json` and when I convert it to List using `gson`, the app crashes. The `proguard` is on and the problem is there.

```
fun getQuestions(): List<Question>? {
    val json = getQuestionsJsonData()
    return GsonBuilder().create().fromJson(
        json,
        object : TypeToken<List<Question>?>() {}.type
    )
}
```

As I've obfuscated my code, I'm not able to see `crash` log in `logcat`, so I send it to `firebase crashlitycs`. The error message is - `Caused by java.lang.RuntimeException: Missing type parameter.`

Maybe the `Question` type get's obfuscated or something similar happens.
My proguard file:

```
-keepclassmembers,allowobfuscation class * {
  @com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName <fields>;
}

-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
    public static <fields>;
}

#Serialized
-keepnames class * implements java.io.Serializable
-keepclassmembers class * implements java.io.Serializable {
    static final long serialVersionUID;
    private static final java.io.ObjectStreamField[] serialPersistentFields;
    !static !transient <fields>;
    !private <fields>;
    !private <methods>;
    private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream);
    private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream);
    java.lang.Object writeReplace();
    java.lang.Object readResolve();
}

# Uncomment this to preserve the line number information for
# debugging stack traces.
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable

# If you keep the line number information, uncomment this to
# hide the original source file name.
-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
```

Maybe I have to add something in proguard file?

**P.S. The problem is only on Gradle 7.1.0**

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/8129040; but it is a bit weird that this only started appearing with Gradle 7.1.0

Comment: Is this even about **Gradle** 7.1 or the **Android Gradle plugin** 7.1.0?

Comment: It's the com.android.tools.build:gradle version in application gradle file.

Comment: [Gson issue #2069](https://github.com/google/gson/issues/2069) describes this problem as well, but there is currently no known solution to this yet (besides your workaround mentioned below).

Comment: Thanks. BTW, I will keep this question, hence someone will find this useful.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Well, after changing my `TypeToken` code, seems it's working.

Non working code:

```
return GsonBuilder().create().fromJson(
    json,
    object : TypeToken<List<Question>?>() {}.type
)
```

Working solution:

```
return GsonBuilder().create().fromJson(
    json,
    TypeToken.getParameterized(List::class.java, Question::class.java).type
)
```

Answer (score 39):

In my case was just adding the following to proguard configuration:

```
# Retain generic signatures of TypeToken and its subclasses with R8 version 3.0 and higher.
-keep,allowobfuscation,allowshrinking class com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken
-keep,allowobfuscation,allowshrinking class * extends com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken
```

Here you go the full set of options that are needed for Gson -> https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/examples/android-proguard-example/proguard.cfg

Comment: Thank you.. this would help if minifyEnabled true

Answer (score 4):

Add these 3 lines inside **proguard-rules.pro** :

```
-keep class com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken
-keep class * extends com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken
-keep public class * implements java.lang.reflect.Type
```

Answer (score 4):

There have been some breaking changes in the Android Gradle plugin v8.0, including the enabling of R8 full mode:
https://developer.android.com/build/releases/gradle-plugin#default-changes

If none of the other options, such as keeping TypeToken classes, works for you, you can add the following command to your `gradle.properties`:

```
android.enableR8.fullMode = false
```

You can read more about R8 full mode here:
https://r8.googlesource.com/r8/+/refs/heads/master/compatibility-faq.md#r8-full-mode

Answer (score 1):

## Add these lines inside proguard-rules.pro

```
# Retain generic signatures of TypeToken and its subclasses with R8 version 3.0 and higher.
-keep,allowobfuscation,allowshrinking class com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken
-keep,allowobfuscation,allowshrinking class * extends com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken
-keep class com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken
-keep class * extends com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken
-keep public class * implements java.lang.reflect.Type
```